# Read data stored with CArchive Ar(&SaveDataStoreDetail, CArchive::store);

Tags: c#, mfc, carchive

i have dat file which stored value using

```
Ar<<sDmdDataStore.iMachineNo;
Ar<<sDmdDataStore.csOptName;
Ar<<sDmdDataStore.csLocationofStone;
```

how to read data back from this file

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your question. Do you want to read a .dat file that has been generated with C and MFC from within a C# program ? Please edit your question and clarify what you want to do exactly,

Comment: ... and please show the data structure of `sDmdDataStore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly like that:

```
CArchive Ar(&SaveDataStoreDetail, CArchive::load);
...
Ar>>sDmdDataStore.iMachineNo;
Ar>>sDmdDataStore.csOptName;
Ar>>sDmdDataStore.csLocationofStone;
```

Comment: which namespace is needed for cArchive . as  i am new in c# so dont know that.

Comment: @RaviSolanki : I'm not sure I've understood your question. Do you want to read a .dat file that has been generated with C and MFC from within a C# program ? Please edit your question and clarify what you want to do exactly,

Comment: @RaviSolanki : this answer is probably wrong as I probably misunderstood your question. Please clarify. I will most likely delete this answer.

Comment: CArchive is part of the MFC C++ library. It is not part of C#. It is not easy to parse. You could consider adding an MFC DLL to parse it for you, or perhaps you can change the MFC program to generate a more open file format.

Comment: i thought carchive is part of c# . sorry for wasting your time .